# cleveref with Hebrew

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, polyglossia, hebrew, right-to-left

The following LaTeX code is saved in the file `~\test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{hebrew}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{mythm}
A house is not a home.
\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
    x+y=z
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

Consider~\cref{mythm}, and compare it with~\cref{myeq}.
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

> cd ~
> xelatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~\test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: cleveref without polyglossia]

If now the two commented lines are uncommented, and the `xelatex test` command is rerun, the execution fails.

Is there a way to get the `cleveref` package to work with Hebrew, with either`polyglossia` or `babel` as the language package? If not, is there another, similar package that works with Hebrew? If not, is there a simple way to emulate the `cleveref` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cleveref package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) comes with several language modules. Unfortunately, `hebrew` isn't one of the package's supported languages. A workaround: load `cleveref` with an explicit language option -- say, `english` -- and then use the `\addtocaptions{hebrew}{...}` device to provide various `\crefname` directives suitable for hebrew. I'm afraid I don't speak or read Hebrew, so I can't be very specific.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}

\usepackage[english]{cleveref} % set an explicit language option
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\appto{\captionshebrew}{%
   \crefname{theorem}{משפט}{משפט}% 3rd arg should be *plural* form of 2nd arg
   % \crefname{equation}{...}{...}% 3rd arg should be *plural* form of 2nd arg
}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{mythm}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}

Consider~\cref{mythm}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work for both Hebrew and English? If I use this patch, then Hebrew references work fine, but English references (from `otherlanguage` environment or `\selectlanguage{english}`) don't work anymore. If I don't use this patch, then English works and Hebrew doesn't. Is there a way to apply this patch only when the Hebrew language is selected?

Comment: @ShaiAvr - You ask a really good question! Unfortunately, I don't understand the `babel` or `polyglossia` machinery well enough to be able to offer a usable answer. It's not by accident that my answer makes use of the `cleveref` machinery, which operates independently of the `babel`/`polyglossia` machinery. It so happens that I'm very familiar with `cleveref`. Unfortunately, nobody has so far provide a Hebrew language module for `cleveref`.

Comment: I would like to help contribute Hebrew translations for `cleveref` (I am a native Hebrew speaker). However, I have no experience with the procedure. I tried to read the [docs](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf#subsection.14.3), but I have no experience with `dtx` files and I don't understand where to find existing definitions to know what needs to be translated and how.

Comment: @ShaiAvr - That's a wonderful offer! Please contact Toby Cubitt, the author of the `cleveref` pacakge, directly. I have to warn you, though, that Toby appears to have moved on from the `cleveref` package to new interests in recent years. The most recent update to `cleveref` occurred in early 2018, and he doesn't appear to answer cleveref-related emails anymore. (At least, he hasn't answered *my* emails in a while...) But if you contact him with an offer to provide Hebrew translations of `equation`, `theorem`, `section`, etc, he might respond. Keeping my fingers crossed!